WEBI: Count student who pass threshold based on running sum
I would like to create a summary report which counts the number of students who have crossed a certain  threshold for the number of hours attended.
I would like to create a summary report which counts the number of students who have crossed a certain  threshold for the number of hours attended.
Detail includes:
calendar week
student_identifier
attendence_hours_running_sum: =RunningSum([Hours in attendance_19592]; ([student_identifier]))
attendance_enrolled_flag: =If [attendance_hours_running_sum] >= 12 Then 1
attendance_enrolled_count: =Count(If [attendance_enrolled_flag] = 1 Then [student_identifier])
The detail report is accurate, but the summary report by week returns 0s for all rows when I would expect



student_attendance_calendar_week
student_identifier




2024_27
1


2024_28
10



Detail table:



student_attendance_calendar_week
student_identifier
attendance_hours_running_sum
attendance_enrolled_flag
attendance_enrolled_count




2024_27
21469
12
1
1


2024_27
26140
0

0


2024_27
28956
0

0


2024_27
32637
0

0


2024_27
48521
0

0


2024_27
53435
4

0


2024_27
53441
0

0


2024_27
54403
8

0


2024_27
55993
4

0


2024_27
56195
8

0


2024_28
9614
16
1
1


2024_28
15563
4

0


2024_28
16816
4

0


2024_28
21469
19
1
1


2024_28
21646
0

0


2024_28
26088
8

0


2024_28
26140
0

0


2024_28
27718
11.5

0


2024_28
28956
0

0


2024_28
31961
0

0


2024_28
32060
11.5

0


2024_28
32637
0

0


2024_28
41012
8

0


2024_28
47154
12
1
1


2024_28
48521
0

0


2024_28
48561
0

0


2024_28
48576
9

0


2024_28
49823
4

0


2024_28
49848
4

0


2024_28
49866
8.5

0


2024_28
52929
3

0


2024_28
52932
7.5

0


2024_28
53209
8

0


2024_28
53212
8

0


2024_28
53213
4

0


2024_28
53215
0

0


2024_28
53221
9

0


2024_28
53431
8

0


2024_28
53435
10.5

0


2024_28
53441
0

0


2024_28
53551
9.5

0


2024_28
53672
8.5

0


2024_28
53711
4.5

0


2024_28
53734
3.5

0


2024_28
54237
12
1
1


2024_28
54361
9

0


2024_28
54363
6

0


2024_28
54387
11.5

0


2024_28
54389
10.5

0


2024_28
54403
8

0


2024_28
55514
0

0


2024_28
55957
8

0


2024_28
55993
8

0


2024_28
55995
2.5

0


2024_28
56021
8.5

0


2024_28
56186
9

0


2024_28
56187
6

0


2024_28
56188
3

0


2024_28
56189
6

0


2024_28
56190
0

0


2024_28
56191
9

0


2024_28
56192
9

0


2024_28
56193
8

0


2024_28
56194
4

0


2024_28
56195
8

0


2024_28
56196
8

0


2024_28
56205
12
1
1


2024_28
56210
12
1
1


2024_28
56211
12
1
1


2024_28
56212
10.5

0


2024_28
56213
5

0


2024_28
56214
6.5

0


2024_28
56215
6

0


2024_28
56216
7.5

0


2024_28
56217
8

0


2024_28
56218
3.5

0


2024_28
56219
12
1
1


2024_28
56220
12
1
1


2024_28
56221
0

0


2024_28
56222
3

0


2024_28
56223
9

0


2024_28
56224
2.5

0


2024_28
56226
8

0


2024_28
56227
8

0


2024_28
56228
8

0


2024_28
56229
4

0


2024_28
56230
4

0


2024_28
56231
0

0


2024_28
56233
0

0


2024_28
56234
5.5

0


2024_28
56235
2.5

0


2024_28
56237
12
1
1


2024_28
56238
5.5

0


2024_28
56239
9

0


2024_28
56240
7.5

0


2024_28
56242
5.5

0


2024_28
56243
6

0


2024_28
56244
9

0


2024_28
56245
8.5

0


2024_28
56246
9

0


2024_28
56247
6

0


2024_28
56248
6

0


2024_28
56249
3

0


2024_28
56250
9

0


2024_28
56251
9

0


2024_28
56252
6

0


2024_28
56254
6

0


2024_28
56255
6

0


2024_28
56256
9

0


2024_28
56257
9

0


2024_28
56258
9

0


2024_28
56268
8

0



